# openvpn and ufw killswitch does not work with dns and automatic ufw update

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn, ufw

So basically I simply want a kill switch so connection is only allowed through VPN. Also I would prefer openvpn to keep try reconnecting indefinitely when the connection brakes.

Tha problem is that I am using CyberGhost as a VPN provider and they provide a domain name as a remote rather then a singe ip address. If this domain name is resolved I get a list of ip addresses. Now this list is changing.

What I did is that I added an up.sh script to openvpn so at every start it resets the ufw, requests the list of ip addresses and adds all of those to the ufw before initiaing the vpn connection.

openvpn.ovpn

```
client
remote 4-1-gb.cg-dialup.net 443
dev tun 
proto udp
auth-user-pass


resolv-retry infinite 
redirect-gateway def1
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
#ping 5
#ping-exit 60
#ping-timer-rem
explicit-exit-notify 2
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
route-delay 5
tun-mtu 1500 
fragment 1300
mssfix 1200
verb 4
comp-lzo
auth-user-pass login.conf
keepalive 10 60

ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key
```

up.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Updating FireWall.."
sh ./firewall_setting.sh
echo "Bringing up the tunnel DNS.."
resolvconf -a tap0 <resolve.conf
```

firewall_setting.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
###########################################
#          Created by Thomas Butz         #
#   E-Mail: btom1990(at)googlemail.com    #
#  Feel free to copy & share this script  #
###########################################

# Adapt this value to your config!
VPN_DST_PORT=443

# Don't change anything beyond this point
###########################################

# Check for root priviliges
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   printf "Please run as root:\nsudo %s\n" "${0}"
   exit 1
fi


# Reset the ufw config
ufw --force reset

# let all incoming traffic pass
ufw default deny incoming
# and block outgoing by default
ufw default deny outgoing

list="$(dig +short remote 4-1-gb.cg-dialup.net)"
for item in $list
do
    ufw allow out to $item
    ufw allow in from $item
done
ufw allow out to  8.8.8.8
ufw allow in from 8.8.8.8
ufw allow out on tun0

ufw allow out 53
# Allow local IPv4 connections
ufw allow out to 10.0.0.0/8
ufw allow out to 172.16.0.0/12
ufw allow out to 192.168.0.0/24
ufw allow in from 192.168.0.0/24

# Allow IPv4 local multicasts
ufw allow out to 224.0.0.0/24
ufw allow out to 239.0.0.0/8

# Allow local IPv6 connections
ufw allow out to fe80::/64
# Allow IPv6 link-local multicasts
ufw allow out to ff01::/16
# Allow IPv6 site-local multicasts
ufw allow out to ff02::/16
ufw allow out to ff05::/16

# Enable the firewall
ufw enable
```

down.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Bringing down the tunnel DNS.."
resolvconf -d tap0
```

resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options edns0
```

When I try to run

```
sudo openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn --script-security 2 --up up.sh --down down.sh --up-restart
```

It works just fine but when I unplug the net cable for 10 sec to simulate a problem and i plug it back I get:

```
Tue Jul 16 11:11:43 2019 us=970540 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Jul 16 11:11:51 2019 us=671314 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]37.120.159.36:443
Tue Jul 16 11:11:51 2019 us=671489 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]37.120.159.36:443
Tue Jul 16 11:11:51 2019 us=671531 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]37.120.159.36:443
Tue Jul 16 11:11:53 2019 us=670882 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]37.120.159.36:443
.
.
.
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=230774 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=230875 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=230958 down.sh tun0 1500 1626 10.248.202.202 10.248.202.201 restart
Bringing down the tunnel DNS..
No resolv.conf for interface tap0
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=234713 WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program exited with error status: 1
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=234744 Exiting due to fatal error
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=234786 /sbin/ip route del 10.248.200.1/32
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=236717 /sbin/ip route del 37.120.159.36/32
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=237808 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=237859 /sbin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=239058 /sbin/ip route del 128.0.0.0/1
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=240052 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=240104 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 10.248.202.202 peer 10.248.202.201
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=287588 down.sh tun0 1500 1626 10.248.202.202 10.248.202.201 init
Bringing down the tunnel DNS..
No resolv.conf for interface tap0
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=292226 WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program exited with error status: 1
Tue Jul 16 11:14:40 2019 us=292267 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Am I doing something wring? Is there an easier way to achieve this? Cause it feels that it should really be something simper then this.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not ideal as it might allow some data to go through before killing the connection when the vpn is not present... I set mine to 1 second, you could try a lot less. See below. The test.wav requires a sound file (it doesnt work well, sounds like a concurrency issue but it does warn me), or omit it.
And mine is for tun0 which is my vpn connection. check yours using

```
ip route
```

when vpn connected and not connected to see the difference.

# note run this with sudo 
  # note 2 update, sudo is not necessary if not automatically reconnecting (prompts for my password anyway).

```
 while (true)
  now=$(date +"%T")     
 do
  (ip route | grep tun0)> route.txt
 if [ -s route.txt ]
 then 
  echo "VPN is connected "
 else
  echo "VPN is OFF stopping internet connection"
  play test.wav  
  service network-manager stop 
  sleep 10
# to start it again 'sudo  service network-manager start'
 fi
 echo "$now"
 echo
 sleep 1
 done
```

to sleep for less than a second, got this one
https://serverfault.com/questions/469247/how-do-i-sleep-for-a-millisecond-in-bash-or-ksh

" Historical implementations of sleep have required that number be an integer, and only accepted a single argument without a suffix. However, GNU sleep accepts arbitrary floating point numbers. See Floating point.

Hence you can use sleep 0.1, sleep 1.0e-1 and similar arguments."

Comment: Thanks for your input I appreciate it. However it does not reconnect by itself so I have to manually do that which I am trying to avoid. Also, it does not update the firewall.

Comment: actually I tried to get it to reconnect automatically with 'sudo  service network-manager start' but it required a password. if there is a way around that problem, it would do it if there was also a command to select the connection and connect. xdotool wtih keystrokes would probably do it, but my ethernet connection ID's change often with the USB adapters.

Answer (score 0):

A new gnome tweak here claims to do just this.the only caveat is that you need to be connected to vpn before enabling it. I have my autoconnect ehternet to vpn on, which is a top bar button that says VP ON or VP OFF , and VPN DOWN when it is down. when connection is lost and reconnected. VPM DOWN must be clicked to get OFF then clicked again to get UP. no settings in TWEAKS. I have no idea how long it takes before disconnecting, but less than my second in my script above.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1898/protectmevpn/

"Will disable all active connections (wifi, wired) if enabled and your VPN is down or offline. 
Be sure to enable your VPN connection before turn VPN-Protection on. To turn it on/off simply click VP-OFF on your menu bar. It will change to VP-ON (VPN-Protected) and protect your privacy. On errors make sure, you have "nmcli" installed (nmcli -v &amp;gt;= 1.16.0)"

a companion tweak is a top bar indicator which is 'VPN is up' or 'VPN is down'.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1134/vpn-indicator/

Comment: ok so this tweak now no longer works with both of my new vpn providers, so I now have to use the script again. as I had issues with stopping the service, I now use 

ifconfig <id> down

where id is derived from ip link  , and therefore if that changes, with a different usb adapter for the internet, another script for each one.